# Limit Kentico search results by user group

Tags: kentico

I'm working out a base requirements for a new kentico build. We want to limit content, either at the page or web part level by user group. What do I need to do to ensure search results only return what a user in a specific group is meant to see.

So three pages, page 2 is restricted to a group 1. Users from group 2 shouldn't see page 2 show up in a search result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can instruct the search web part to check the permissions of the results. Select **Check permissions**.

It will now check each user/role against your permission settings on each page.

see: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Searching+according+to+page+permissions

Comment: Thanks, i'll be playing with this tomorrow and this really helps.